# Get Computer Group Membership without AD Search

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

Is there an equivalent for getting the computer's AD group membership, without running an AD search? I need to be able to retrieve the group SIDs of the computers group membership in AD, even when machine does not have connectivity to the domain controller, running as a standard user account.

Essentially looking for the equivalent of this, except for the current computer account.

```
$groups = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups
```

Comment: Since that information is in AD, no, you cannot get it *without* actually talking to AD, I'm afraid ...

Comment: Yes it's possible to get it because this information is cached, at least the SIDs are, as per the user group membership example I gave, which shows user AD group membership (as SIDs of the groups) with no AD connectivity. An example for computer groups is gpresult /h out.htm will show the SIDs for computer domain group membership without AD connectivity. I will do some further analysis how gpresult gets it.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out how to do this by reverse engineering `gpresult`. To do this, first as an Administrator I granted standard users access to `WMI` namespace `root\rsop\COMPUTER`

I would prefer a solution without having to do this, but requires further investigation.

One time setup of machine using script [Set-WmiNamespaceSecurity.ps1](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/Management-Articles/PowerShell-Script-for-setting-WMI-Permissions-for-User-ID/ta-p/53646)

```
Set-WmiNamespaceSecurity.ps1 root/rsop/COMPUTER add Users Enable
```

Now I can retrieve the Active Directory computer group `SIDs` from machine is in, as a standard user, even when it's not connected to a network with following PowerShell:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\rsop\COMPUTER" -Class RSOP_Session -Property SecurityGroups).SecurityGroups
```